# How to assign or append a unique ID in javascript with row integer from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp-1.3

I have rows of forms with unique ID and its own Submit button. I used a for loop to get my rows.
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count($areaList) ; $i++ )

sample html output below.

In my javascript, I need #loading and #result to reference the unique id="loading(int)" in my html so that the message displays next to that row.

At first, I had the div id="loading" and div id="result" w/o the integer in each row of my table but the message, 'Saved'  would only display in my first row (first place it found that ID). I need my ids to be unique but how can I append them to my javascript?

I need some direction in js... I've attempted:

```
var rows = getElementsByClassName('reply_form');
for (var i=0, ii=rows.length; i<ii; i++)
rows[i]


var loading = $('#loading').attr('value');
$('#loading').prepend(""+loading+"");
```

-- not sure where to go....

```
 <form id="1" class="reply_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/reports/addcounts/" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" /><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="977ceaa782a964fe9a3f5a1cb3d7d422e8470af9" id="Token108437306" /></div>    
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="data[Report][id]" value="184463" /><b>Room</b><br />207  <input type="hidden" name="data[Report][area]" value="1" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[Report][tables1]" type="text" class="inputbox" size="3" value="0" id="ReportTables1" />           </td> 
        <td><input name="data[Report][chairs1]" type="text" class="inputbox" size="3" value="0" id="ReportChairs1" />           </td> 
        <td><input name="data[Report][comments1]" type="text" size="20" value="" id="ReportComments1" />            </td>
        <td>
            <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div><br />
            <div id="loading1" style="display: none;">Saved</div>
            <div id="result1" style="display: none;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</form>

    <form id="2" class="reply_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/reports/addcounts/" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" /><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="977ceaa782a964fe9a3f5a1cb3d7d422e8470af9" id="Token108437307" /></div>    
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="data[Report][id]" value="184464" /><b>Room</b><br />208  <input type="hidden" name="data[Report][area]" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[Report][tables2]" type="text" class="inputbox" size="3" value="0" id="ReportTables2" />           </td> 
        <td><input name="data[Report][chairs2" type="text" class="inputbox" size="3" value="0" id="ReportChairs2" />            </td> 
        <td><input name="data[Report][comments2]" type="text" size="20" value="" id="ReportComments2" />            </td>
        <td>
            <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div><br />
            <div id="loading2" style="display: none;">Saved</div>
            <div id="result2" style="display: none;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</form>

    <form id="3" class="reply_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/reports/addcounts/" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" /><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="977ceaa782a964fe9a3f5a1cb3d7d422e8470af9" id="Token108437308" /></div>
<table>
<tbody> 
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="data[Report][id]" value="184465" /><b>Room</b><br />209  <input type="hidden" name="data[Report][area]" value="3" /></td>
        <td><input name="data[Report][tables3]" type="text" class="inputbox" size="3" value="0" id="ReportTables3" />           </td> 
        <td><input name="data[Report][chairs3" type="text" class="inputbox" size="3" value="0" id="ReportChairs3" />            </td> 
        <td><input name="data[Report][comments3]" type="text" size="20" value="" id="ReportComments3" />            </td>
        <td>
            <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div><br />
            <div id="loading3" style="display: none;">Saved</div>
            <div id="result3" style="display: none;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.reply_form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/reports/addcounts/',
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          cache: false,       
          beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loading').show();
            $('#result').hide();
          },
         success: function(data) {
            if(data==1) {
              $('#loading').hide();
              $('#result').fadeIn('slow').html("ok");
              $('#result').addClass('true');
              $(this).slideUp(1000);
            }
            else {
              $('#loading').hide();
              $('#result').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
              $('#result').addClass('errors');
            }
          }    
        });

         return false;
      });
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: I think you'll find the HTML is invalid. `<tbody>` should contain only `<tr>` elements (and their legal descendants). Forms can wrap an entire table or you can have a forms inside table cells, but nothing in between. Some Doctypes may be tolerant of `<tbody><form>...</form></tbody>` but there's no guarantee.

Comment: thanks...I'll work on fixing html but I still need to figure out how to append the integer $i from php to the id in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not positive I understand the question, but it seems like you want to reference which of the forms were submitted, and manipulate just those  #result and #loading divs? if so...

In the success function you retrieve the DOM element that initiated the event with jQuery, and then append that to each of the #loading and #result divs.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.reply_form').submit(function(event) {
         currentId = event.delegateTarget.id;          
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'form.php',
             data: $(this).serialize(),
             cache: false,       
              beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loading'+currentId).show();
                $('#result'+currentId).hide();
            },
         success: function(data) {
              if(data==1) {
                  $('#loading'+currentId).hide();
                  $('#result'+currentId).fadeIn('slow').html("ok");
                  $('#result'+currentId).addClass('true');
                  $(this).slideUp(1000);
               }
             else {
                $('#loading'+currentId).hide();
                $('#result'+currentId).fadeIn('slow').html(data);
                $('#result'+currentId).addClass('errors');
             }  
      }    
    });

     return false;
  });
```

}):

That should work assuming that you have a relation between the id's of your forms and their result and loading divs.

Comment: thanks, this helped. I was looking for proper syntax to append an Id to my $('#loading') etc. So, $('#loading'+currentId) was extremely helpful. I did not have success with: currentId = event.delegateTarget.id; so I changed that to currentId = $(this).attr("id"); and kept $('reply_form').submit(function(). I'm getting it to save, show the div #loading (better written as "saving") and the slideUp works. #result has problems. I plan to add a check mark adjacent to my submit button on success and after slideUp so it shows the user the row has been submitted and saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Sloga, with this kind of thing you don't need separate forms and you should be working, for the most part, with classes not ids.

The trick is to attach a click handler to the Submit buttons, then in the handler **work relative** to the `this` (the clicked button) to find all the associated elements. This way, ids are not necessary.

HTML will be something like this :

```
<table id="reply_table">

<tbody>
<tr>
<td><b>Room</b><br />207</td>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    <input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="977ceaa782a964fe9a3f5a1cb3d7d422e8470af9" id="Token108437306" />
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Report][id]" value="184463" />
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Report][area]" value="1" />

    <input name="data[Report][tables1]" type="text" class="inputbox" size="3" value="0" id="ReportTables1" />
</td> 
<td><input name="data[Report][chairs1]" type="text" class="inputbox" size="3" value="0" id="ReportChairs1" /></td>
<td><input name="data[Report][comments1]" type="text" size="20" value="" id="ReportComments1" /></td>
<td>
    <div><button class="submit">Submit</button></div>
    <div class="loading" style="display: none;">Saved</div>
    <div class="result" style="display: none;"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

And the javascript will be something like this :

```
$(function() {
    $('#reply_table').on('click', "button.submit", function() {
        var $tbody = $(this).closest("tbody");//find relevant tbody relative to the clicked button
        var $loading = $tbody.find('.loading').show();//find the relevant "loading" div and show it.
        var $result = $tbody.find('.result').hide();//find the relevant "result" div and hide it.

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/reports/addcounts/',
            data: $tbody.find("input").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $loading.hide();
                if(data==1) {
                    $result.html('ok').addClass('true').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                        $tbody.slideUp(1000);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $result.html(data).addClass('errors').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

*untested*

I'm not sure if `tbody` elements will slideUp in all browsers. You may need to compromise and `.hide()` instead.